# Checked radio buttons not working right in jQuery modal dialog in sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i added both the check box and radio button to my page but when i try check the radio button or check box does not respond: but it does work properly in a simple html page, by the way the these components are added to a jQuery Dialog:

code :

```
   <fieldset title="Language Source"> 
       <legend>Langue Source</legend>           
                            <label><input type="radio" name="langueSource"   
      value="Anglais" id="Ang" />Anglais</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="langueSource" 
      value="Français" id="Fr"/>Français</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="langueSource" 
      value="Allemand" id="Al"/>Allemand</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="langueSource" value="Arabe" 
      id="Ar"/>Arabe</label>
    </fieldset>


             <fieldset id="field">
                    <legend>Langue Cible</legend>  
                        <!-- Here I want my set of radio button -->
            </fieldset>
```

generation of radios

```
          $().SPServices({
           operation: "GetListItems",
           async: false,
           listName: "Dictionnaire",
           CAMLViewFields:"mycamlquery",
              CAMLQuery: "myviewfields",
              completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

              $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

                var langue_source =  $(this).attr("ows_Langue_x0020_entr_x00e9_e");

                var langues_cible =  $(this).attr("ows_Langues_x0020_sortie").replace(/#
                /g,"").split(';');


                for (var i=1; i<langues_cible.length-1; i++) {

                    $("<label id='" + langues_cible[i] + "_label'>")
                        .text(langues_cible[i])
                        .prependTo("#field");

                    $("<input type='checkbox' value='"+langues_cible[i]+"' />")
                        .attr("id", langues_cible[i])
                        .attr("name", "langueCible")
                        .attr("value", langues_cible[i])
                        //.attr("checked", "checked")
                        .prependTo("#" + langues_cible[i] + "_label");

                  }

                })
             }
         });
```

[image]

Comment: what does it does not respond mean? is it supposed to do something? code might be useful

Comment: does not check any of them

Comment: Instead of 'attr('checked', 'checked'), try with 'prop('checked', true)'

Comment: the problem in the click event when i try to set it by firefox console it does work, i don't not if there's any interference in events